# How to make VoiceOver "not" to interact with an image element?

Tags: accessibility

It seems there is not much documents out there explaining my question or even mention about.
Hoping anyone can helps me with this.

Having an simple image on the website, let's say
`<img src="..." alt="some meaningful text">`

Screen reader in Google extension works well as expected when reading the image that it says "some meaningful text".

However, the VoiceOver reads it as "some meaningful text, image", "You are currently on a image... To begin interacting with the contents of this image, press Control-Option-Shift-Down Arrow. To exist...".
And that is incorrect.

I don't want the VoiceOver to let users interacts with the image which is not able to, but don't know how to achieve.

Comment: I’m afraid that your questions has been answered plenty of times but not in the way you’d expect. The answer is: Don’t mess with the screen reader. If you are not a screen reader user (or maybe an a11y expert), you are in no position to decide what would be “correct” or “incorrect”. There is good reasons screen readers announce what they do, they are highly customisable, and their users are very used to their announcements. Also, plenty of screen reader users are sighted, and knowing that something is normally an image is meaningful to them.

Comment: Why do you say users could not interact with the image? Did you try Control-Option-Shift-Down-Arrow? What did it do?

Comment: Yes, after doing Control-Option-Shift-Down Arrow, it shows "No visible to interact". 
Here is what I'm thinking, the image is just for presentation, no further actions will be took on this image. So maybe the VoiceOver could simply announce "some meaningful text, image" to the users and that's all good. Instead of telling the user that if you want to interact with the image press "Control-Option-Shift-Down Arrow".